# Laplace–Beltrami operator And Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand how to use Laplace–Beltrami operator to calculate the curvature of a surface.

We first need a surface in isometric coordinates, let assume it is

$$\frac{1}{y^2}\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0  \\
    0       & 1 
\end{pmatrix}  $$

The equation is $$K=-\frac{1}{2}\bigtriangleup_{LB}(ln(\lambda))$$

So we have $$K=-\frac{1}{2}\bigtriangleup_{LB}(ln(y^{-2}))=-\frac{1}{2}(0+2y^{-1})=-\frac{1}{y}$$?

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace operator in a surface $S$ with isometric coordinates $ds^2=\lambda^2(dudu+dvdv)$ is given by
$\Delta_S f = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}(f_{uu}+f_{vv})$ so we can't use the ordinary definition in Euclid plane. And the curvature is given by $K=-\Delta_S Ln\lambda$

In your special case, $K=-\frac{1}{2}\bigtriangleup_{LB}(ln(y^{-2}))=\bigtriangleup_{LB}(Ln y)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2}}(-\frac{1}{y^2})=-1$